# FB.getLoginStatus doesn't fire callback in native Android browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

This problem had just showed up in my app when I view it on the native Android browser in ICS and Jellybean. All works as intended on desktop browsers and even Chrom for Android. This has occurred in the past few days, was working fine last week, and nothing in the code has changed.

The following code, which is a simplified version of what my app does, is essentially what I'm doing to initiate a connection to FB. I'm expecting the alerts in A and B, or A and C will pop, but instead, nothing happens.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '', // App ID
        channelUrl: 'http://localhost/fb/channel', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        alert("any response"); //<-- A
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            alert("connected"); // <-- B
        } else {
            //somehow user was not already signed in or did not fully authorize
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    alert("connected"); // <-- C
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
        ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Anyone experiencing that same and have a workaround or solution?

Comment: theres a lot of us with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364827/fb-getloginstatus-suddenly-stopped-working-on-android-browser

Comment: Zynga is reporting the error now as well. FB has made it a High priority: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/176760275805232?browse=search_513e5aa4e725a0135277100

Comment: Update: Facebook will release a fix on Tuesday 26 March [link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/176760275805232?browse=search_513e5aa4e725a0135277100)

Comment: Confirmed, this has been fixed!

Comment: Now apparently is broken again. Argh Facebook!

Comment: Yeah android 4.1 its so irritating how can they not test their stuff out first on critical sdks!